# I keep getting the error backcard not defined, even though I have defined it

Tags: python

In my class, I define backcard = self.backcard, however no matter where I put it, when I run my program to go through the main function, I keep getting the error that backcard.isClicked isn't defined.

```
class MemoryGame(Deck, PlayingCard):

    def __init__(self, fulldeck):
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.fulldeck = fulldeck
        self.deck.shuffle()

    def gameboard(self, win, xpos, ypos):
        gameboard = self.gameboard
        dealtCard = self.deck.dealCard()
        suite = dealtCard.getSuite()
        rank = dealtCard.getRank()
        self.cardlist = []

        for rowsofcards in range(4):
            backcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
            self.backcard = backcard
            ypos += 130
            xpos = 190
            for rowsofcard in range(6):
                rowsofcards = self.deck.dealCard()
                randomsuite = rowsofcards.getSuite()
                randomrank = rowsofcards.getRank()
                cardimage = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/"+ (randomsuite) + str(randomrank) +".gif")
                cardimage.draw(win)
                backcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")
                backcard.draw(win)
                self.cardlist.append(backcard)
                xpos += 100
                self.backcard = backcard
        self.backcard = backcard
```

I have it written in 3 different spots just to show the placement I've tried, and nothing works. then If I put that part of the code before the for loop, I get that backcard is referenced before the assignment. This is also the part that is getting the error in my main function:

```
while not Quitbutton.isClicked(p):
        #Start Game
        if StartGameButton.isClicked(p) and player == True:

            if first == True:
                Game.gameboard(win,110,6)
                if backcard.isClicked(p):
                    backcard.undraw()
                first = False

                if StartGameButton.isClicked(p):
                    p = win.getMouse()
                    if backcard.isClicked(p):
                        backcard.undraw()
                        p = win.getMouse()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Game.backcard` in `main()`?

Comment: _I keep getting the error that backcard.isClicked isnt defined_. `backcard` is an instance of the `Image` class.  Do `Image` objects have an `isClicked()` function?

Comment: `class MemoryGame(Deck, PlayingCard)` - you have severely misunderstood how inheritance works.

Comment: @John Gordon, they do not. isClicked is strictly for a button class I have. So i know my program will crash there, but that's for another issue I'll have to figure out. I can't test my program until i figure out how to call this backcard though

Comment: You might try my first suggestion.  You didn't define `backcard` as a global variable.  You defined it as a local variable in `gameboard()` and as an instance attribute.

Comment: @zondo so call it in the main() function `Game.backcard = self.backcard`? Or in the for loop say `if Game.backcard.isClicked(p)`

Comment: I mean in the `for` loop.  You could make it easy on yourself by just putting `backcard = Game.backcard` right before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What's most likely happening is that something is calling the `backcard` property of `MemoryGame` before `gameboard()` is called. You can verify this by setting `self.backcard` in the `__init__` function.

Really all your class variables should be initialized to something in the constructor. Try setting it equal to `None` in `__init__` and you should see the error change to `NoneType has no attribute...` and that should help you track down what is attempting to access it before it's ready.

Comment: No, actually the problem is that he is using `backcard` as if it were a global variable instead of an instance attribute.

Comment: When I put it in the `__init__` portion, I then get the error `NameError: name 'backcard' is not defined` even though it is defined right there

Answer (score 0):

in `gameboard` method, you are calling `self.backcard = backcard` **after for loop** but local variable `backcard = Image(Point(xpos,ypos),"playingcards/b1fv.gif")` is defined **inside for loop**. try to move it out before you enter the for loop.